# Why i getting duplicates when i import XML?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I spent half a day to understand and I don't know what to do.
I have an XML file with 146 565 records of name and class with import XML

```
    public function parse() {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $q = 1;        
        while ($this->reader->read() && $this->reader->name !== 'licenses');
        while ($this->reader->localName === 'licenses') {
            $node = simplexml_import_dom($this->doc->importNode($this->reader->expand(), true));
            $inn = (string) $node->inn;
            $name = (string) $node->name;            
            $this->service->create($name, $inn);
        }
        echo 'Time script: ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 4) . ' sec.';
    }
```

when i use `echo $name` instead of `$this->service->create($name, $inn);` it works fine. I get 146 565 names on my screen. But when I add it in MySql with my service, the script doesn't stop. When I to a test file with 1000 lines it imported into the database well.

```
MariaDB [dbbase]> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM names_table;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|   248778 |
```

My service

```
public function create(string $name, string $inn): bool {

        try {
            $this->sth->execute([
            ':uuid' => Uuid::uuid4(),
            ':name' => $name,
            ':inn' => $inn
        ]); 
        return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How to solve it? I understand than it is something wrong with service but i don't know what to do. I try without `return true` and with it - script doesn't stop. 
P.S. Added id (primary, auto_increment) instead of uuid - result the same.

Comment: why do you have 2 `while` iterators ?

Comment: Move to first  <licenses /> node. It works when i do it with echo inly

Comment: Remove almost all of the names and classes from the XML. Leave 1-2. If the problem in not present, then it's maybe and issue with data in the XML - special character breaking the service for example. Or maybe an issue with the size of the file. If you still have the issue with even just 1-2 names and classes - remove the classes section. Check it if the name section is running smoothly, and if not try the other way around too. Use xdebugger and trace the code or dump the variables and their values into a log file, and examine how the code works.

Comment: If the code has no problem with 1-2 names/classes you can use binary search, by putting back the half. Then execute the script again. If fails, take the half of them again. If not fails check the initial other half just in case. Repeat until you find the issue - if the issue is in the XML

Comment: If you can identify an example of one that is duplicated, try and extract just that element from the XML and see how it runs with just that records data.

Comment: When you echo 146,565 things to the screen it works and completes, but when you try to put it into the database it doesn't ever complete? Is that the problem? If so, try echoing and putting into the database. My guess is that your database insert is taking too long and eventually timing out.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by splitting the processing in two parts:

```
public function parse() {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $q = 1;        
        while ($this->reader->read() && $this->reader->name !== 'licenses');
        $pairs = [ ];
        while ($this->reader->localName === 'licenses') {
            $node = simplexml_import_dom($this->doc->importNode($this->reader->expand(), true));
            $pairs[] = [ (string) $node->name, (string) $node->inn, Uuid::uuid4() ];
        }
        echo 'Time script: ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 4) . ' sec.';

        foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
            list($name, $inn, $uuid) = $pair;
            print date('H:i:s') . " inserting {$name}\n";
            $this->service->create($name, $inn, $uuid);
        }

        echo 'Time script: ' . round(microtime(true) - $start, 4) . ' sec.';
    }
```

If the problem is that the inserts take too long, you can change your query strategy by having two prepared statements, one with say 200 pairs, one with a single one, so that you can insert multiple lines with a single INSERT. That should accelerate things nicely. Otherwise, there *are* more gruesome solutions :-).

Notice that above I have offloaded the UUIDv4 creation to the first cycle, **which requires you to change the service create call to read uuid from the parameters**. This is because I once hit a beautiful bug in the use of the PHP `random_bytes()` function, that blocked the system if the source of randomness (which could have been `/dev/urandom` but actually somehow was `/dev/random`) depleted.

If the revised code blocks in the first loop (before any SQL code got even called), **then it is your UUIDv4 call that is flawed** and we can see about fixing it.